# iterating object keys inside array iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/163xq7j3/) is my fiddle of getting all values of input in a table. I am getting the value if and only if on set of data is available I also happened to have `add` meaning I can add new set of data. My question is how to iterate again through the new added set. Currently I am not iterating to the new set I am only getting the last set of data

im using an object to store input values , how can i iterate over this object to store every input value as object key ?

`UPDATE`

Output expected

`[{
    "First Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Smith",
    "Middle Name": "Lee",
    "Suffix": "Jr",
    "City/Province": "JohnCity",
    "Town/Municipality": "JohnTown",
    "Barangay/District": "JohnDistrict",
    "Contact Number": "8973897923",
    "Street": "123",
    "member": "complainant"
}, {
    "First Name": "James",
    "Last Name": "Harden",
    "Middle Name": "Lin",
    "Suffix": "III",
    "City/Province": "JamesCity",
    "Town/Municipality": "JamesTown",
    "Barangay/District": "JamesDistrict",
    "Street": "123",
    "Contact Number": "1234123421",
    "member": "complainant"
}]`

Comment: I would like to know what is problem with the question why i got -2

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I can tell you that: your question is unclear and should be more detailed. The fiddle is ok, is a good point to have, but you should have your code always in plain text in the question.

Comment: what do you think is the problem why i only insert the last set of values in array?when i try to console the value of an input example `first name` and i have 3 sets, i can get the value of the 3 input text with the first name id. but in the array i only get the last one. @LelioFaieta

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing data in a single object , so you are iterating over rows , but not iterating over that single object keys , for object iteration use `for..in` , read **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** for more info of how to loop on object keys.

**Edit:**

I have noticed that you are pushing data outside your loop , thought you should push them inside the each loop ! here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/163xq7j3/4/)**

Comment: i cant understand the sample in the link can you give more precise example

Comment: i also made that one but the output i want is like the one in update